# Notation help abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

If $R$ is a ring and $x$ is an indeterminate, what does the notation $R(x)$ mean? I've seen $R[x]$ but not $R(x)$.

Comment: IS IT THIS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension?

Answer (score 1):

$R(x)$ usually means the field of rational functions over $R$, i.e $\{\frac{f}{g}: f \in R[x], 0 \neq g \in R[x]\}$. (Alternatively, you can view this as the field of fractions of $R[x]$).

Comment: OK GREAT THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Note that $R$ needs to be an integral domain for this to make sense.

Comment: OTHERWISE YOU CANNOT TAKE THE FIELD OF FRACTIONS, CORRECT?

Comment: Yes.  Please stop using all caps though.

Comment: SIR MY KEYBOARD IS BROKEN